# Angular.js passing object from a jsp to the app scope

Tags: java, jsp, angularjs

I am wondering if it is possible to pass an object using Gson (probably) from a JSP page where my app is located to the scope of my app? (In a nice way)

I want to avoid using an AJAX request to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the common pattern of inlining your data in JavaScript to avoid making an initial AJAX request.

In your JSP, you can write out the JSON into the body of an Angular service module as array or object hash data.  The service module would just return this inline data and then you can make it available to the rest of your Angular app via service injection.

Comment: could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

As Will suggested, make the JSP variable a part of the markup, the server will replace the relevant part. Psuedocode follows:

```
<%String contextPath=request.getContextPath();%>


<script src="<%=contextPath%>/static/js/lib/angular.v1.2.16.min.js"></script>    

<script>
app.service('contextService', [function() {

    this.getResourcePath = function() {
        return '<%=contextPath%>/resources/' ;
    };
}]);
</script>
```